# wiring usb cables for powering multiple devices via a bus terminal

Tags: power-supply, usb, dc

[image: usb thing]

Hi all,

I have a created a home brew cable to power up a monitor and a raspberry pi zero, and I have blown up a capacitor on the monitor card, and I have no idea why :(

**First question:**
Why did the capacitor blew up?

The monitor has an LDVS to HDMI board which receives power via a usb mini-b, and the pi receives power by a micro usb. I have taken both usb cable, stripped them and soldered the red wires together, as well as the black wires together. I then used a 2 pin JST SM wire by soldering again, red with red, and black with black.

Here is a pic of the contraption

The JST connects to a 8 way bus bar. The bar is connected to a Mean Well RSP-320-5 rated for 5 Volts at 60 Amps, and the positive line has an inline fuse rated for 20 Amps.

The first time I power everything up, I had everything connected before turning the switch on, and the fuse blew up. The second time I connected the power but left the USB unconnected. First I plugged in the pi, and while the fuse didn't blow up, the pi didn't turn on. Then I unplugged the pi, and plugged the monitor, 5 seconds later the capacitor sparked, some smoke came out, and my face became painted with sadness.

I am using different cable gauge, 14 from the power supply all the way down to 22 for the JST cable, and whatever gauge the usb wires have in there (it's thinner than 22 but I am uncertain what gauge that would be)

I have confirmed the there is only continuity from the red and black cable with their corresponding usb pins.

*PS: I tried the usb to jst before, with the male end directly connected to the screw terminal on the power supply, and everything worked, so I am double confused...*

**Second question:**
How can I test this without... blowing hundreds of dollars worth of equipments up?
Is there something I can build or buy that would allow me to check my power circuitry in a safe manner?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Usually capacitors only blow up because of either overvoltage or reverse voltage. Have you confirmed your red and black wires go to their respective Ground and 5V lines using a ohmmeter/voltmeter? Colors never mean anything unless proven correct.

Comment: buy and use a DMM ... it will save you lots of grief in the long run

Comment: for posterity.. it was absolutely a blown up capacitor, because I'm dumb, didn't check the polarity, and assumed that red is positive and black is negative. Lesson learnt.
Thanks for the tip!